# Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:jar'

Tags: java, maven-3

I'm getting the following error during a maven build today.

```
Unable to resolve artifact: Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:jar': Cannot find parent: org.apache.tiles:tiles-parent for project: null:tiles-core:jar:null for project null:tiles-core:jar:null
08:52:47   org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:jar:2.0.6
08:52:47 
08:52:47 from the specified remote repositories:
08:52:47   apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots),
08:52:47   central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
08:52:47   nexus (http://10.210.40.37:8081/nexus/content/groups/public)
08:52:47 
08:52:47 Path to dependency: 
08:52:47    1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:pom:2.0
08:52:47    2) com.p.v.a.legacy:bo:jar:3.113.0-SNAPSHOT
08:52:47    3) com.p.v.a.legacy:s2-common:jar:3.113.0-SNAPSHOT
08:52:47    4) org.apache.struts:struts2-tiles-plugin:jar:2.3.16.3
```

I think its because the site : dtddoc.sf.net shows 
"Project web is currently offline pending the final migration of its data to our new datacenter."

Which maven is downloading as a pom, then finds out is not valid.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Note: I'm using Maven 3.0.5, JDK 7

Note: Clearing the .m2 folder makes no difference. It stil failes to find the metadata.

Comment: Clear .m2 folder jars and again the maven build and check it.

Comment: Or, maybe, just cross your finger and wait for the migration to complete

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to SourceForge's official blog, they are moving their data into a new data center. So, all websites (hosted by their servers) get this message during the time:

```
Project web is currently offline pending the final migration of its data to our new datacenter
```

You can read more about this maintenance at: https://sourceforge.net/blog/upcoming-sourceforge-hardware-refresh/.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error. It comes from:
http://javaxdelta.sourceforge.net/maven2/repository/
The are doing some maintenance work and every request responds:
"Project web is currently offline pending the final migration of its data to our new datacenter."
And now when maven goes to get the pom.xml from their repo it writes this string down as pom.xml :S

My solution was to refactor my maven repo references, to get rid of the sourceforge reference, because I got all I needed from central anyway.

Comment: We also had a similar problem with a repo.  We're using Artifactory and removed it from the list of remote repos (it was only there for one project anyway).  It was happening even though all of the artifacts I was using in my project were present in other repos that it was checking first, so if any of the repos are from source forge (go to the actual url to see if you can browse their artifacts) you may get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Because of [data migration](https://twitter.com/sfnet_ops/status/962041749030952962), SourceForge moved their data in a long time:

```
This coming week, Feb 12th-Feb 15th, SourceForge & @Slashdot will be cutting over to a new datacenter.
We will be working hard to ensure that there will be as few issues as possible, but we want to inform the community in the event any issues arise.
```

---

Today, they announced that [everything started working](https://twitter.com/sfnet_ops/status/965055907557269504) normally:

`Update: Project website hosting and SFTP uploads have been restored. Thanks for your patience.`

So, you will not get the error during a Maven build.